# Adding objects to hasMany error

Tags: ember.js

My form has body and subject inputs, and an input for tags, so the user can enter any number of tags (saved to tagList) and then submit the request. Problem: JSON.stringify(z) does something like this

New request:{"subject":"this is subject","body":"this is body","tags":["fixture-0","fixture-1"]}

instead of getting the tags to be the text I entered, I get fixture-0...

```
import Ember from "ember";
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    tagList: [],

    actions: {
        addRequest: function() {

            var z = this.store.createRecord("Request", {body: this.get("body"), subject: this.get("subject")    
            });

            this.get("tagList").forEach(function(entry){
               console.log("adding tag to request: "+entry.get("tagt"));
                z.get("tags").pushObject(entry);
            });

            console.log("New request:" + JSON.stringify(z));

            z.save();

        },

        addTag: function(){

            console.log("adding " + this.get("tag"))
            var t = this.store.createRecord("tag", {tagt: this.get("tag")});
            this.get("tagList").pushObject(t)

        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you can rely on `JSON.stringify` to convert your records to JSON properly, that's generally the job of a serializer. (Although I guess the `toJSON` method on the object could defer to the serializer, but I don't think it does.)

Second, this is expected behavior for Ember-Data. The names of the text aren't in the JSON because they don't need to be. You have a `hasMany` relationship, which means that the record only keeps references (IDs) to tag objects. Keeping the actual text in the object would be duplicating that information.

As a side note, judging by the fact that you're using `Request` as a model type name, I can say with a pretty good degree of certainty that you're using Ember-Data incorrectly. This may be part of the reason you aren't expecting Ember-Data to behave the way it is. I would suggest reading [Ember's guide on models](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/) to better understand what Ember-Data is for, and why it's probably not a good fit for your use case.